# Is there a MC PC Commands to MC Bedrock Edition Commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Ok so im trying to get his specific command to work:

**/give @p minecraft:sign 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Text1:"{\"text\":\"\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"tp @p 500 12 0\"}}",Text2:"{\"text\":\"Click Here\",\"underlined\":true,\"color\":\"yellow\"}",Text3:"{\"text\":\"For Help\",\"underlined\":true,\"color\":\"yellow\"}"},display:{Name:"Help Sign"}}**

And i'm not sure how to get it to work correctly, since i used a generator to get this command.... (I'm not at all experienced in commands like this) So if you have a tried and true method to convert it, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly, the Bedrock edition of minecraft has no access to nbt in commands, so giving yourself this item is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

No. Bedrock is vastly different than Java when it comes to commands. Bedrock has no nbt arguments, so what you're doing is not possible.